# C# Identify Network Connected To

Tags: c#, networking

I'm working on an app that will copy files to a server.

I need a way to determine if the client is physically attached to the network (LAN cable or wirelessly attached), or if the client is connecting via some other way.

For example, if my app was running on my laptop at the office I might be plugged in. Later I disconnect and go home and my laptop is then connected to my router and my provider.

I thought of checking the domain name but that just gives me the name of my dev PC. I also considered seeing if a file share is available, but if someone who was NOT really connected created a mapping with the same name then its a false result.

In the end the app will determine how it's connected, and then either do a file copy or FTP the file in.

How can I tell how it's really connected?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear.  It sounds like you're actually asking whether you're on the _same_ network.  Just try connecting to the hostname.

Comment: how are you checking the domain name.. are you using PrincipalContext also I believe that you can do this also using `WMI` this can also be found doing the following `System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName;`

Comment: @slaks..Yes, I'm trying to determine if I'm on the same network.  Please explain "connecting to the hostname"

Comment: @MethodMan: I just ran the following:

string name1 = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
string name2 = Environment.UserDomainName;
string name3 = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry("").HostName;

On At my office name1 is the PCName, name2 is the NetworkName and name3 is PCname.NetworkName

At home all 3 are the PCName

Comment: @MethodMan. I tried System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().Domain‌​Name;  On the office network I get the network name. On my home PC which is on my home network it returns empty